# Draw ten dots that are all the same distance apart

Tags: mathematics, visual, geometry

I am wondering, is it possible to draw ten dots so that every dot has the same distance to every other one?

And how many possibilities are there?

Comment: In how many dimensions?

Comment: Two dimensions.

Comment: this seems equally relevant in mathematics S.E.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No: three dots having the same distances to each other form an equilateral triangle, and there is no way to add a *fourth* to have the same distance to all three of those. It would have to be on all three of the circles in this image:
[image]

(So it *certainly* isn't possible to do 10 dots!)

In general, you need $n-1$ dimensions for $n$ dots with this property: these dots will form the vertices of a regular $k$-[simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

Comment: You didn't *prove* it though ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor And *you* didn't generalize it. :P

Comment: I am not good at math. But i think the highest possible number of dots is 7. is it right ?

Comment: @ran No - as shown in the answers here, the highest possible is 3 (in the plane).

Comment: @Randal'Thor :D, Yea.. you are right.. what a stupid question i asked :P

Comment: @ran, you may be thinking of a related question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/56809/228

Comment: @PeterTaylor No :-), I was thinking about this (6+1 points) > https://goo.gl/images/52KoY5

Answer (score 21):

Sure, there's one possibility:

[image]

Each dot has a distance of 0 from all others.

Answer (score 7):

In two dimensions, there is

> a trivial solution: the dots are identical (i.e. at the same place), the distance is trivially zero.

also:

> You never said you want Euclidean solutions :-). If the distance is defined by [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space), then the distance between any non-identical dots is trivially 1.

EDIT: answer to how many possibilities there are:

> for the trivial solution - one

> for the non-Euclidean - infinity. And there are other non-trivial metrics you can use, e.g. Chebyshev distance works as well.

Comment: Yay for brainbreaking non-euclidian space!

Answer (score 6):

### In two dimensions, no.

Instead of ten, the most you can get is **three** dots all at the same distance from each other.

To see why this is, let's start with two dots $A,B$ a given distance apart (say 1 unit). Where can we place a third dot which is 1 unit away from both of them? This dot must be on both of the radius-1 circles centred at $A$ and $B$, and these circles only intersect in two points:

[image: diagram]

The two points $C1,C2$ aren't distance 1 apart, so the most we can get is three dots, forming an equilateral triangle in the plane.

### In three dimensions, no.

A similar argument in 3D space shows that the most you can get is **four** dots all the same distance apart, forming a regular tetrahedron in 3-space.

### Only in nine or more dimensions.

As Deusovi correctly says in his answer, the general solution in $n$ dimensions is the vertices of a simplex (the higher-dimensional analogue of a triangle or tetrahedron) - such a shape has $n+1$ vertices, all of which are equidistant from each other, and it's impossible to do better than this. So in a space of dimension 9 or higher, it *is* possible to find ten points all the same distance apart. But we'd need to ask a string theorist for that ...